# Is it possible to find out why linker links a particular static library?

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

I have a small C++ application that **statically links** a framework library, let's call it *F*, providing me various kinds of features. For some of them the *F* framework uses another **static** library *L* which therefore I also have to link. It is quite big and I am sure I do not need it for my application (it takes care of things that I do not use in the application at all, even remotely).

Until now the linker seemed to optimize out whole *L* library because the parts of the *F* framework that I was using did not need it. But it has changed after migrating to a new version of *F* and size of my application's binary has been increased really dramatically. This is something I would like to avoid.

Is there some way how could I tell the linker to provide me information why is not something optimized away? Or which of my functions/methods use perhaps indirectly some stuff from the *L* library? Is it even possible? Based on this kind of info I would be hopefully able either to alter the *F* framework in a way that would prevent incorporating the *L* library code into the final binary, or implement my application a bit differently and not use some part of the *F* causing this.

I am talking about Microsoft Visual Compiler here. But maybe Clang or GCC could help me better here?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Don't link L, see what breaks.

Comment: Link explicitly with the static version of `F`, but don't use the `-static` flag to link all libraries statically. Then if `L` have a shared library, it will be used instead.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx

Comment: You could try adding "/verbose" to the linker command line.